# What data format dose azure-search support for import zip file from blob?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have read the document [Indexing Documents in Azure Blob Storage with Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage).

In this document, they say they support **ZIP** format,but not mention which data format they support? I try to import ZIP JSON file but fail.

Does any one have any suggestion ?